# UIWebView needs to load URL with ID from device

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` that I need to load a page with a specific URL that pulls a number from the users iPhone.

I have the following code

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *deviceUDID = [myDevice uniqueIdentifier];

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/test.php?uid="]]];
```

How do I place the `deviceUDID` at the end of `mysite.com/test.php?uid=`

Comment: [NsString stringwithformat:"url+%@",deviceid] ?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done a number of ways.

```
NSString *query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/test.php?uid=%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:query];
```

Note, if you're looking to simply log the UDID, you don't need to use a webView. You could even just use the following code:

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
if(response)
    //success
else
    //no response from server
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, couldn't you use

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"....%@", uid]`

Remember, the %@ will replace an NSString.